# How to call PHP function using Ajax (Javascript, PHP and Yii1.1)

Tags: javascript, php

I am looking to call a PHP function through an onclick event. The PHP action within the controller then should start a download for a json File containing the needed data.

I already know ajax and I am using it currently but somehow the function does not fire. I am 100% certain that I am doing something wrong, but I can't seem to find what.

The ajax works great so far and the `console.log()` at the end can be seen in the console. However, the function the request should trigger in my controller, does not go off. Either that or I am trying to log the wrong thing. Every bit of help is appreciated.

I am using Yii 1.1 and CButtonColumn.

admin.php:

```
'buttons'=>array(
  'export' => array(
          'label'=>'Export',
          'click'=>'function() {
            $.ajax({
              url: "/path/to/admin.php/followed/by/controller/action/actionExport",
              method: "POST",
              success: function(result) {
                console.log("Hello there!");
              }
            });
          }',
          'imageUrl' => Yii::app()->request->baseUrl.'/images/image.png',
        ),
```

The adminController.php containing the action. Maybe I should mention that the controller is on another directory one level above the admin.php

```
public function actionExport(){

    if (isset($_POST)) {
      Yii::log(It was a great success, I think!");
    }

    $helper = new TestHelper();
    $data = $helper->actionIndex();

    header("Content-type: application/json/xml");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=report.json");
    header("Pragma: no-cache");
    header("Expires: 0");

    echo json_encode($data);
  }
```

Comment: I did not work with Yii , but it seems that your "url" is not firing, because you are not seeking on the public url of your application server and you are not  checking if your request "isJson()". Look at these sources: [this one](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/runtime-routing#creating-urls) and [this one](https://forum.yiiframework.com/t/making-an-ajax-request-to-a-yii-controller-method-from-a-javascript-function/79682/3)

Comment: Your URL seems to be strange. How is your routes written? URL must be valid accessible URL.

Comment: You guys where right. The problem was all in the URL. After I changed it, it worked like a charm. Thanks a lot.
I will post the answer as soon as i can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So thanks to some hints I was able to resolve the question and get it done. It was a problem with he URL and got to be done like so:

```
'url'=>'Yii::app()->createUrl(Yii::app()->controller->module->id."/".Yii::app()->controller->id."/export",
                array("id"=>$data["group_id"]))'
```